# How to add “Edit” button on product in cart page?

Tags: product, cart, ce-1.4.1.1

I need to add an "Edit" button on my cart page products.
I think "Edit" button on cart products has been added after magento version 1.5.x
Is there any way I can add "Edit" button on cart products without upgrading? If yes then where I should make changes for this?
Please reply if you have any idea.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to start from the very beginning.

I will give you the starting point which is common between `ce-1.4.x.x` and `ce-1.5.x.x`. It is `checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` template.

In `1.5.x.x` the new column was added into the table. You should do the same.

This require `getConfigureUrl()` method in your `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer` class. So you also have to copy this method.

This method is referencing to `configureAction()` method at `Mage_Checkout_CartController`. Copy it also.

I'll stop at this point and let you continue :-)

Comment: Thanks Tim for pointing me at the right direction. I can start from this point.